# Enable submit button if input and checkbox aren't empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below I am trying to ensure that my checkbox and inputs are all filled before allowing user to submit. It ignores my check on the checkbox and opens up the submit after the fields only are filled. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#first, #last, #pass').bind('keyup', function() {
    if (allFilled()) $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
});

function allFilled() {
    var filled = true;

    console.log($('#checkbox').prop('checked'))

    $('body input').each(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == '' && $('#checkbox').prop('checked') == false)  filled = false;
    }); 

    return filled
};
```

html:

```
<body>
  <form>
    Username
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first" />
    <br /> First
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="last" name="last" />
    <br /> Last
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" />
    <br /> Password
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="register" disabled value="Register" />
  </form>
  <div id="test">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Seeing your HTML would be useful. [mcve]. You should also be using `.on()` instead of `.bind()`

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki that was indeed my problem if you answer i'll vote you correct

Comment: Your checkbox don't have value attribute `<input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Please don't use the deprecated method **[`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead :

```
$('#first, #last, #pass').on('keyup', function() {
    if (allFilled()) $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#first, #last, #pass').on('keyup', function() {
  if (allFilled()) $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
});

function allFilled() {
  var filled = true;

  $('body input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '' && $('#checkbox').prop('checked') == false)  filled = false;
  }); 
  return filled
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Username
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="first" name="first" />
  <br /> First
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="last" name="last" />
  <br /> Last
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" />
  <br /> Password
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="register" disabled value="Register" />
</form>
<div id="test">
</div>
```